# How can I send a native token from a contract to an externally owned account in an ink smart contract?

Tags: ink, smart-contract

How can I send native tokens from a contract address to a user/externally owned account using an [Ink](https://use.ink/) smart contract?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using [transfer](https://docs.rs/ink_env/latest/ink_env/fn.transfer.html). See example [here](https://github.com/paritytech/ink-examples/blob/b5a5a554f85e9bd07d288ab319d14f15e6e509af/payment-channel/lib.rs#L213)

```
        self.env()
            .transfer(recipient, amount)
            .map_err(|_| Error::TrasnferError)?;
```